# Understanding the definition of $\Delta$-complexes.

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex

I'm reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology and on page 103 he gives a definition of a $\Delta$-complex which requires, among other things:

> A $\Delta$-complex structure on a space $X$ is a collection of maps $\sigma_{\alpha}:\Delta^n \to X$, with $n$ depending on $\alpha$, such that:
>
> (i) The restriction $\sigma|{\mathring{\Delta^n}}$ is injective, and each point $X$ is in the image of exactly one such restriction $\sigma|{\mathring{\Delta^n}}$.
>
> ...

Among other examples, Hatcher gives this one for a Torus:

[image]

I can see how how this has 2 2-simplices ($U$ and $L$), 3 1-simplices ($a$, $b$, and $c$), and 1 0-simplex ($v$). However, I can't see how the point $v$ qualifies under requirement (i) above - it is on the boundary of all six simplices unless I'm misunderstanding something. For $0$-simplices, does the single point qualify as the interior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the same page, Hatcher defines the notion of the face of a simplex, and then defines $\mathring{\Delta^n}$ to be $\Delta^n - \partial \Delta^n$, where $\partial \Delta^n$ is the union of the faces of $\Delta^n$. Hatcher's definition of a face implies that $\partial \Delta^0 = \emptyset$. Hence $\mathring{\Delta^0} = \Delta^0$: i.e., the interior of a $0$-simplex is indeed its single point, as you conjectured.

To reconcile this with the topological notion of interior, think of an $n$-simplex as a subspace of its affine span, which is $n$-dimensional. Hatcher's definition then agrees with the topological definition, because when $n=0$, the affine span is a topological space comprising a single point, $x_0$ say, and in that space $\{x_0\}$ is open and is its own interior.

Comment: That makes sense to me given your explanation of Hatcher's definition. But here is why I find it strange. The interior is usually a space minus it's boundary and the boundary is all the limit points. In this case, $x_0$ is a limit point and, therefore, on the boundary, no?

Comment: @roundsquare The boundary can be defined as the set of limit points *that do not belong to the interior*. But the notion of "interior" is not an intrinsic property of a topological  space, but rather a property of subsets of a given space: the $x$-axis viewed as a subset of the plane has an empty interior, but viewed as a subset of itself, it is equal to its interior.